# "Il nous faut..." et "Je me suis rendu compte que..."

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-personnels, standard, dialectes

Est-ce que des expressions comme :

- Il nous faut [acheter qqch.]
- Je me suis rendu compte que [je n'ai pas d'argent avec moi]

...sont grammaticales ?

Plus précisément je parle de l'emploi de *nous* et *me*, qui, il me semble, ne sont pas ni COD, ni COI dans ces (*il me semble...* aussi?) J'ai entendu ce genre des phrases utilisées si fréquemment que j'ai pris l'habitude de parler de cette façon moi-même. Néanmoins, je soupçonne qu'il ne s'agit pas ici du français standard, mais plutôt du langage courant ou d'une dialecte.

Comment: Grammaticales, sûrement, mais *je n'ai pas d'argent **avec** moi* n'est pas très idiomatique (voire pas du tout). On dira plutôt: *je n'ai pas d'argent **sur** moi*.

Comment: @jlliagre merci pour cette correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dans les phrases avec *il faut* comme « Il nous faut [acheter qqch] » le pronom *nous* est un COI.  Le complément d'objet indirect répond à la question *à qui faut-il...?*.  La réponse, à *nous.*  Par exemple,

- Il nous faut des assiettes pour manger. *nous* = COI
- Il me semble que... (à moi) *me* = COI

Mais *se rendre compte* est un verbe pronominal donc dans la phrase *je me suis rendu compte* c'est *compte* le complément direct et un pronom réfléchi (à qui ? *me, te, se...*).  Les pronoms se ressemblent mais le sens est différent.

Oui, ces locutions sont grammaticales mais l'usage avec *il nous faut + infinitif* vs *il faut que nous ...*, ça dépend.  Notez bien les commentaires [What is the difference between “il te faut ~” and “il faut que tu ~”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/34116/1893)

Answer (score 1):

"*Il nous faut*" est la forme impersonnelle "*il faut*" (en Anglais "*it must be*") appliquée au pronom "*nous*": "*Il nous faut*" signifie "*nous devons*".

Si "*il faut*" + *verbe* est très courant (ex: "*il faut partir d'ici*"), "*il nous faut*" + *verbe* est au contraire une forme littéraire que l'on ne rencontrera pas, ou très rarement, dans la langue parlée (ex: "*Il nous faut partir d'ici*": Dans la forme parlée, on dira "*nous devons partir d'ici*").

En revanche, la forme "*il nous faut*" + *nom*, comme dans l'exemple ci-dessus ("*Il nous faut des assiettes pour manger*") est très courante.

Answer (score 0):

Les mots “me” et “nous”, peuvent être des [COD](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronom) (section “Pronom français”).
Les phrases sont donc grammaticalement correctes.

Comment: Je connais les pronoms COD et COI... mais j'ai la difficulté de visualiser cettes pheases, si les objets n'étaient pas des pronoms...

Comment: Dans ces phrases, *me* et *nous* ne sont pas des COD.